# Make an Animation in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, animation, android-animation

I know how to create a frame-by-frame animation in Android studio. I've been using Paint to create a bunch of images and uploading them in an  in order to create a custom animation.

However, there must be a better way to do this? Can I use some 2-D animation software to create an animation and then upload it to android studio?

Any thoughts/suggestions on how to efficiently make custom animations (for example, a guy running)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can look at Lottie, perhaps : https://airbnb.design/lottie/ (has support for android and ios) and it greatly improves and enhances these animations too (it converts them to smaller Json files).

here are some examples of what you can do with it : https://lottiefiles.com/

it's just for small gifs and loading animations, but you can create your own using Adobe After Effects, maybe this helps

Comment: Huh interesting, thanks for the site! Never heard of it before but I really like it! Might use it in my app!

Comment: Yeah definitely, animation drawables are fine but they're a pain to make! Thanks again, appreciate it :D

Answer (score 0):

if you have only few images, then its very simple to do , you just need to create  resource file in drawable folder, just use `<animation-list>` tag and add all images as `<item android:drawable="@drawable/seq1" android:duration="100">` with particular delay. Like mentioned on [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawable-animation). 
For example:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_camera_arrow_00001" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_camera_arrow_00002" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_camera_arrow_00003" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_camera_arrow_00004" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>

val frameAnimation = imageView?.drawable as AnimationDrawable
frameAnimation.start()
```